# Visual Studio 2017 ToolsVersion 15.0

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am attempting to implement a proper development cycle into the business I work for and something as simple as a repository and subversion they have never used.

I have a colleague who has a brand new machine with a brand new install of Visual Studio 2017, myself and another colleague also have VS2017 installed however when using SVN (TortoiseSVN/VisualSVN) to create projects we are not having any issues as both our VS2017's are creating the projects with ToolsVersion 15.0.

The other colleague with the brand new machine can't read from the repo or push anything to it because of incompatibility with the ToolsVersion. Every project he creates in his VS is creating at ToolsVersion 4.0.

This is causing me an issue as he's one of the mine BI Developers and of course nothing is going into the Repo at the minute as a result of this.

I've tried making sure MSBuild Tools 15 is on there but I cannot seem to get his VS to create a new project in anything but ToolsVersion 4.0.

Really need some help here, I've been through tons of forums etc. and cannot seem to move past this.

Comment: Do you mean if `the other colleague` creates a simple C# console project in vs, open its .csproj file we'll find the ToolsVersion is 4.0 instead of 15.0? Have he tried to repair vs?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT That is exactly what is occuring, he's tried a repair and he's totally formatted his machine (for other reasons) and re-installed and still nothing.

Comment: It seems one issue about VS installation, perhaps something does some changes to the msbuild.exe.config file or any other files, My suggestion is to uninstall the vs2017 completely and turn off firewall and install the latest vs2017 to check if it helps.